# Custom message or redirection for 400 bad request (because of unexcaped % on params) in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I got 400 Bad Request if i request

```
http://localhost:3000/cont/act?params=%
```

On the log it only show

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.14 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[Zonebie] Setting timezone: ZONEBIE_TZ="Tokelau Is."
dalton
>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
!! Invalid request
```

How can i make custom message or redirect for this kind of error ?

P.S

I've try using few different middleware solution on google.

Like adding

```
class InvalidUriCatch
  puts "Hello"

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    puts "hello"

    query = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(env['QUERY_STRING'].to_s) rescue :bad_query
    if query == :bad_query
      [302, {'Location' => 'google.com'}, "<a href=\"google.com\">a</a>"]
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

on my libs and put

```
config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Static, "InvalidUriCatch"
```

on application.rb

But still, doesn't work

it didn't even  output hello on `rails s` log when i request it.

Comment: you can keep a static file/image in public folder. This can be displayed in case some action fails showing maintenance etc.

Comment: @GhostRider that is not the solution i want. I want it to be flexible. So it can work to any routes i have. But thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code doesn't work because i'm using Thin on my development (My application using passenger on production. ).

That's why on production it show error with backtrace while on local it doesn't.