# Parse windows-1252 param in rails action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, windows-1252

My API is receiving a call that contains windows-1252 encoded data in the POST body.
In rails 6.0.3, this apparently worked. But rails 6.1.1 throws ActionController::BadRequest (Invalid request parameters: Invalid encoding for parameter.

Edit: I can not change the calls to UTF-8, those come from a 3rd party. So, my API must accept windows-1252 encoding.

Here is a snippet that emulates this call:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:3030/dummy/create")
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request.content_type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

# Rack::QueryParser::InvalidParameterError: Invalid encoding for parameter:
#G�bor
name = "Gábor".encode("windows-1252", "utf-8")
request.body = "last_name=#{name}&first_name=Sam&charset=windows-1252"


response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, nil) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end

# 400
pp response.code
```

And on the server side, the `dummy#create` action is never reached, it stops with

```
Started POST "/dummy/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-02-06 17:14:12 +0100
  
ActionController::BadRequest (Invalid request parameters: Invalid encoding for parameter: G�bor):
  
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/request/utils.rb:39:in `check_param_encoding'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/request/utils.rb:34:in `block in check_param_encoding'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/request/utils.rb:34:in `each_value'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/request/utils.rb:34:in `check_param_encoding'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:403:in `block in POST'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/request.rb:69:in `fetch'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/request.rb:69:in `fetch_header'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:398:in `POST'
actionpack (6.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:55:in `parameters'
...
```

I found that I could register a middleware to intercept this kind of call, as described in [Rails/Rack: "ArgumentError: invalid %-encoding" for POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769681/rails-rack-argumenterror-invalid-encoding-for-post-data)

The middleware would then check for the 'charset' param in the POST, and this probably would work. However, this has the disadvantage that it would apply to all calls, not only the `dummy#create` endpoint.

Since this behavior was recently introduced, (in rail 6.1 I assume), is there a better way now to handle this?

Comment: I have this same issue. What did you end up doing to solve the problem?

Comment: Still unsolved. The middleware solution did not pass tests, so I did not yet deploy. Since then I did not retry to find a solution. It is blocking upgrade to rails 6.1

Comment: The bug has nothing to do with the `charset` parameter. I just finished the test setup and reproduced your bug, but it's almost morning here, will play with it tomorrow at night.  Im interested in solving it.

Comment: @Kjell did you end up solving this? Trying to bypass check_param_encoding for incoming emails from SendGrid Parse API which gets handled by Griddler's email_processing.rb file but struggling to override the POST method.

Comment: @PaulArterburn The accepted answer was the solution. In my first comment to it, I misunderstood how it works, therefore the comment might be misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here, adding `param_encoding`  for each parameter like document https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParameterEncoding/ClassMethods.html

```
param_encoding :create, :last_name, Encoding::ASCII_8BIT
param_encoding :create, :first_name, Encoding::ASCII_8BIT
```

Comment: The input simulates real world request that are made to my API. They come from a different company, and I can not change their requests.

Comment: Sorry but your request always has  `charset` type params right ?

Comment: I don't have a guarantee, but yes, all requests in the logfiles have that charset param, and it is always windows-1252 . In case the param is not there, or it is not windows-1252, I think it would be fine to fallback to rails default behavior.

Comment: I try one solution but it maybe have security problem,First I disable check params encoding on rack, and in action on controller I get last_name by `last_name = params[:last_name].encode('utf-8', 'windows-1252')`. It return `Gábor`

Comment: Disabling check_param_encoding lets the G?bor value pass. I looked further in that direction and found https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0cbc6114dc052faf66eab6a844964b93d1e7a4f6

Comment: @Kjell Do you resolve this problem, I come from upwork and see your post :D, it seem interesting problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234745/discussion-between-kjell-and-binh-trng).